# Errors when starting gatsby server after running it perfectly ( gatsby develop )

Tags: reactjs, favicon, gatsby, static-site

I'm creating my portfolio with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) and reactjs. I was running the static server with `gatsby develop` on localhost. I installed [gatsby-favicon-plugin](https://github.com/Creatiwity/gatsby-plugin-favicon) to add favicon to my site, I configured it correctly and didn't get any result (favicon wasn't still showing). At the moment static server was running without any errors and then I stopped it and started again. Now I'm getting errors when I run `gatsby develop` to start the server.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.009 s
success open and validate gatsby-config.js — 0.006 s
error UNHANDLED REJECTION


  SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function (28:0)

  - index.js:4454 Parser.pp$5.raise
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:4454:13

  - index.js:2066 Parser.pp$1.parseReturnStatement
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:2066:10

  - index.js:1848 Parser.pp$1.parseStatement
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:1848:19

  - index.js:5910 Parser.parseStatement
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:5910:22

  - index.js:2268 Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:2268:21

  - index.js:1778 Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:1778:8

  - index.js:1673 Parser.parse
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:1673:17

  - index.js:7305 Object.parse
    [personal]/[babylon]/lib/index.js:7305:37

  - resolve-module-exports.js:36 module.exports
    [personal]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/resolve-module-exports.js:36:21

  - validate.js:101 
    [personal]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/validate.js:101:29

  - Array.forEach

  - validate.js:93 collatePluginAPIs
    [personal]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/validate.js:93:20

  - index.js:73 _callee$
    [personal]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:73:15

  - next_tick.js:131 _combinedTickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7
```

And this is my `gatsby-config.js` .

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Pankaja's Portfolio`,
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet', 
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: "xxxxxxxx",
        // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
        head: false,
        // Setting this parameter is optional
        anonymize: true,
        // Setting this parameter is also optional
        respectDNT: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-favicon`,
      options: {
        logo: './src/assets/me.png',
        injectHTML: true,
        icons: {
          android: true,
          appleIcon: true,
          appleStartup: true,
          coast: false,
          favicons: true,
          firefox: true,
          twitter: false,
          yandex: false,
          windows: false
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this (as I followed instructions). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if `gatsby-plugin-favicon` got installed successfully?

Comment: Yes @Developer107, It was installed successfully. I tried removing *node_modules* folder and reinstalling them. But no luck on that end.